# Should i say Bismillah silently or loudly?

Tags: salat, allah

Is it OK if I say Bismillah silently  ( in my mind  ) ?

Or should I say it loudly  ?

Eg : Before eating

Comment: Say it Whalen and where? Please take your time to write a well elaborated question and read [ask].

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Then what is the tag [tag:Salat] for?